# What If we don't login for more than 6 months?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

1. What if we don't use our Stack Overflow account for more than e.g. six months?
2. Will the account be deleted?
3. Can we change the password of the account that is getting login through a gmail account?

Comment: I think you'll lose moderator status after 6? months of *complete* inactivity, but that's it. Nothing for normal users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Old inactive accounts are culled as detailed in blog:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

but the rules are quite strict, so if you've done *something* on the site your account won't get automatically deleted.

> We came up with these two rules of thumb. If..

> 1. the user has not visited the site in six months
>    AND
>    2. the user has not done anything of significance, ever

> .. their accounts are effectively abandoned. We don’t believe those users are ever coming back. With that in mind:

> We delete cookie-based unregistered accounts when:

> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>    AND
>    2. The user has less than 50 reputation, and no visible (not-deleted) posts

> We delete OpenID registered accounts when:

> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>    AND
>    2. The user has only 1 reputation, no visible posts, and no other accounts on the network

As far as I know these rules have not changed.

Comment: Oh Great ChrisF...Appreciate your Reply..A very Good Knowledge is being Shared here..Thank you..!!!+100000 from me

Answer (score 11):

Nothing will happen to an "inactive" account.

When you login through OpenID your Stack Exchange account doesn't have a password, the only password you could change is the one of e.g. your Google account if you used the Google OpenID to log in.

If you used the [Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) provider, you can change your password on its website.

Comment: You mean that SO accounts will never get InActive Mode??

Comment: @Haresh, nope, there is no inactive mode. We'll see that *you* are inactive (`last seen: 6 months ago`), but your account will remain functional at all times. You can even keep gaining reputation from your existing questions and answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi your answer has convinced me..!!Good One..

Comment: Thanks @ThiefMaster...+1 from me too.